# If subquery returns no rows, return 0 else return value of the subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I got a question and you can most likely help me.
I have got a query with a subquery that narrows the search. The query ends with this.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Purchase
WHERE
    Total < 5000
AND 
    Total > 
            (
                SELECT TOP 1
                   buyamount
                FROM
                   employee
                WHERE
                   manager = 'TST'
                ORDER BY
                   buyamount ASC
            )
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

I want the value of the subquery after the ">"... but if the subquery gives nothing in return, i want it to be 0. How do i do this?

Comment: You can  use ifnull like **IFNULL((SELECT TOP 1 buyamount FROM employee WHERE manager = 'TST' ORDER BY buyamount ASC ),0)**

Comment: There is no TOP in mysql should this question be tagged sqlserver? or are you trying to port the query to mysql?

Comment: @P.Salmon your right! sorry for that. It's for a widget

Comment: You can use `COALESCE` like this: `COALESCE((...subquery here...), 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you posted you could simply wrap the subquery in [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and get your desired result.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #Purchase
WHERE
    Total < 5000
AND 
    Total > COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT TOP 1
                   buyamount
                FROM
                   #employee
                WHERE
                   manager = 'TST'
                ORDER BY
                   buyamount ASC
            ), 0)
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

You could also use a variable in your provided example instead of a subquery. I prefer this approach because it separates the logic, making it easier to read. Subqueries can also be a performance killer. Having it broken out like this, it should perform better.

```
DECLARE @BuyAmount INT
SET @BuyAmount = (SELECT TOP 1 BuyAmount FROM #Employee WHERE Manager = 'TST' ORDER BY BuyAmount ASC)
IF @BuyAmount IS NULL SET @BuyAmount = 0

SELECT * 
FROM #Purchase
WHERE Total < 5000 AND Total > @BuyAmount
ORDER BY Date DESC
```